# How to create a route which points to a component in react

Tags: reactjs, datatable, routes, react-router

I have a table which is as shown below[image]

I have a component which displays the details

How to display the details when click on the first tab of the table

i.e, when clicked on the number 1053 in the first column how to redirect to component with the parameter

Not sure how to build the route localhost:3000/#/sitepage/1053

Is there a way to directly get the route localhost:3000/#/sitepage/1053 so that i can give in the href of the table

```
Read about https://www.tutorialspoint.com/reactjs/reactjs_router.htm
```

but not sure how this link to route to write

Please point me to a document which will help me in doing

Answer (score 0):

It you want to redirect to another component, you can use [React Router Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect)

This section of React Router documentation will help you, since you haven't posted any code you tried I assumed you're looking for just some documentation to guide you.

### Update:

Ok let's assume you have a `Router` like that:

```
<Router>
    <Route exact path="/" render={(props) => <Table {...props} />}/>
    <Route exact path="/column-details/:id" render={(props) => <ColumnDetails {...props} />}/>
</Router>
```

The `props` here has a [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md) attribute, so in your `<Table>` you can have access to it by initializing your component like this

```js
function Table({history}) {
     // ...
}
```

Now in the first column, you need to add an `onClick` listener, let's say you use `<TableCell>` that would be

```js
<TableCell onClick={() => history.push(`/column-details/${yourId}`)}/>
```

Now in your `<ColumnDetails>` component, we will need access to [match](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/match.md) attribute to extract our `id` from the url, so it would be something like:

```js
function ColumnDetails({match}) {
    const id = match.params.id;
    // ...
}
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: @DhanaLaxshmi I've added an example

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try `react-router-dom` to solve your problem, `react-router-dom` is a wrapper on top of `react-router`, which brings more flexibility

Let say your table is under `Equipments` component, then you have to add `<Link/>` component as alternate to `<a>` as follows, assuming your `equipment` object got `url` and `title` property

```
<Link to={`${equimpement.url}`}>{equimpement.title}</Link>
```

Please note that if you want to use `Link` component you have to import it on top

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
```

And you can manage your routing in your App.js like this way

```
<div className="content">
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/not-found" component={NotFount} />
    <Route path="/equipments/:id" exact component={EquipmentForm} />
    <Route path="/equipments" component={Equipments} />
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Redirect to="/not-found" />
  </Switch>
</div>
```

Make sure you have imported `Route`, `Redirect` and `Switch` as well in your on top of your App.js

```
import { Route, Redirect, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
```

**Update**

And last if you want to use Route in your app you must wrap your  with BrwoserRouter

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

with its import `import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";`